# How to access and change keystone.js sign in page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, keystonejs

I am new to keystone.js and I am trying to figure out where the sign in page is written. I cannot find the sign in page inside keystone.js files. Could anyone tell me how to get that sign in .hbs file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the powered by Keystone, just go in your node_modules folder in your project, look for keystone>admin>client>Signin>Component>SignIn.js.

Open it and at the bottom you will will find the div "auth-footer", you can modify it there.

```
<div className="auth-footer">
  <span>Powered by </span>
  <a href="http://keystonejs.com" target="_blank" title="The Node.js CMS and web application platform (new window)">KeystoneJS</a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The login page on KeystoneJS which by default is accessible at URL `http://***.***.***.***:3000/keystone/signin` is not among the template `*.hbs` files. Login page is developed with **ReactJS** as part of the *Admin UI*. However, you can customize the login page by setting KeystoneJS options like `signin logo` image:

```
keystone.set('signin logo', '../correct/path/logo.png');
```

Among configurable options, I think the URL of login page can be customized too.

As can be seen in the following screenshot, the Wappalyzer plugin on Mozilla Firefox shows that the login page is developed with JavaScript framework **React**, which is used in KeystoneJS package to develop the *Admin UI*:

[image]

---

UPDATE

> ... how do I change `Powered by KeystoneJS` on signin page ...

I'm not quite sure, there might be an option for it which I'm not aware of. However, I know that the signin page is available on [this source code file](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/master/admin/client/Signin/Signin.js). As shown on the following screenshot, at the end of that source file, there is the `Powered by` text and also a `<a href='...'></a>` link tag corresponding to `KeystoneJS` text. You can start playing around with this source file and see how you can modify and transpile it. Also it is a good idea to ask a question about it on KeystoneJS [GitHub Issues page](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues).

[image]

Comment: thank you so much. I still have one question. How do I change the texts such "Powered by KeystoneJS" on the sign in page?